# inserting Blog images into the content

Tags: magento2

How do insert into a blog? There is an ability to use one image at the top but I want to put images into the body of the blog content

Comment: Greetings Alexor, welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a Magento forum and it appears your question is related to a blog. Can you specify how you want your blog integration to work with Magento?

Comment: I post blogs from website admin page, from the Magicart drop down menu. The blog creation page allows me to add one image which shows up next to my blog title on the bottom of my home page. I want to be able to insert images into the body of the blog as well as text, to better illustrate what I am posting about

Comment: I am using Magento 1.9.2.1 and our website is www.class-watches.com

Comment: I just looked at the toolbar above the content area and found an "insert/edit image" hopefully that will work